# Intellij idea thymeleaf completion in spring boot project

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having a code assist issue in a SpringBoot / Thymeleaf project in Intellij idea.

I have setted up a simple Spring boot project using gradle and I want to use thymeleaf as a template engine; however I'm not getting any code assistance in my HTML pages.

The application runs properly however the only code assistance that I have is for the i18n messages, no code assistance for POJOs or any other thing.

My project has the Spring facet configured.

I'm running :

- Intellij Idea 2016.2
- Spring boot 1.3.6

Do I have to do anything else in the project to have this working?

Thanks

Ulises

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this is a known bug from Intellij :

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132738

for which there's no fix yet but only a workaround :

```
<!--/*--><!--@thymesVar id="loginFormBean" type="sample.system.login.LoginFormBean"--><!--*/-->
```